# SQL Server 2012 Audit Report Generation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, audit

Trying to work out whether audit files output by one server can be read without CONTROL SERVER access on that server.  The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx) suggest this is possible:

> Even when the Database Engine is writing to a file, other Windows
>   users can read the audit file if they have permission. The Database
>   Engine does not take an exclusive lock that prevents read operations.

and also:

> We recommend that you generate audit reports from a separate instance
>   of SQL Server, such as an instance of SQL Server Express, to which
>   only Audit Administrators or Audit Readers have access. By using a
>   separate instance of the Database Engine for reporting, you can help
>   prevent unauthorized users from obtaining access to the audit record.

In short, can I do this?

- configure Audit on Prod DB to output to fileshare
- give audit readers read access to the fileshare
- use sys.fn_get_audit_file('fileshare*') from a separate DB to produce audit reports.

[Clarification]
The critical part of the q is, can you access the file using sys.fn_get_audit_file from a separate DB, without having admin access on the DB from which the audit information is created.  That way we can have audit readers with filesystem access separate from DBAs with DB admin access.  Sorry for not making this clear initially.

Speaking with respect to your answer, can this query be run from an unrelated SQL Mgmt Studio/DB, by somebody who is not a DBA on the original DB?

```
SELECT 
    event_time, action_id, session_id, object_id, class_type, 
    database_principal_name, database_name, object_name, statement
FROM 
    sys.fn_get_audit_file('\\Temp\Audit\*',NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: Did your try the short steps you've listed above? Did you try something else?

Comment: @mceda - I won't have access to SQL 2012 until at least mid January, I plan on trying this with SQL 2008 in the meantime as the docs look similar.

Comment: The only part that I didn't try is the bullet point 3 - a separate DB would not matter - the user accessing the files is your SQL Server service user.

Comment: @mceda - thanks again - you have already done plenty to earn the bounty but the separation of user responsibilities (Auditor of live data should not have to be a DBA) is critical.

Comment: No matter what I've tried with context switching, stored procedure hat reads the file and more, on a same server, I was not able to empower my ordinary user with sufficient power.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this works.

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE SERVER AUDIT [SQL2012-Audit-20121214-Demo]
TO FILE 
(   FILEPATH = N'\\Temp\Audit'
    ,MAXSIZE = 2 MB
    ,MAX_FILES = 32
    ,RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF
) WITH (QUEUE_DELAY = 2000,ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE)
GO

ALTER SERVER AUDIT [SQL2012-Audit-20121214-Demo] WITH (STATE = ON);

USE [Performance]
GO

CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [SQL2012-DBAudit-20121214-Demo]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [SQL2012-Audit-20121214-Demo]
ADD (SELECT,INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE,EXECUTE ON DATABASE::[Performance] BY [dbo])
WITH (STATE = ON);
GO
```

After the server audit and the database audit were put in place and activated, the first audit file was immediately created and it was impossible to delete it because Windows stated that the file is in use.

However, selecting from the file works all the time. Here's the "workload" with activity that is supposedly caught by the audit set-up:

```
SELECT * INTO partition_stats_4 FROM Performance.sys.dm_db_partition_stats
SELECT * INTO partition_stats_3 FROM Performance.sys.dm_db_partition_stats
SELECT * INTO partition_stats_2 FROM Performance.sys.dm_db_partition_stats
SELECT * INTO partition_stats_1 FROM Performance.sys.dm_db_partition_stats
SELECT * INTO partition_stats   FROM Performance.sys.dm_db_partition_stats

DELETE FROM partition_stats
DELETE FROM partition_stats_1
DELETE FROM partition_stats_2
DELETE FROM partition_stats_3
DELETE FROM partition_stats_4

DROP TABLE partition_stats_4
DROP TABLE partition_stats_3
DROP TABLE partition_stats_2
DROP TABLE partition_stats_1
DROP TABLE partition_stats
```

And here's the result:

```
SELECT 
    event_time, action_id, session_id, object_id, class_type, 
    database_principal_name, database_name, object_name, statement
FROM 
    sys.fn_get_audit_file('\\Temp\Audit\*',NULL,NULL);
```

[image: SQL Server 2012 - DB Audit Results]

By the way, this is exactly the same pattern when it comes to the server side trace files. We have traces running all the time and the files are "query-able" without any trouble.

Happy auditing!

Comment: I don't have an environment in which I can test the read-only access to the active audit file. However, selecting the records out of that same audit file copied over from production to a different environment, was working on a different server, once the user has `CONTROL SERVER` permission.